# Explode comma separated integers to intvals?

Tags: php, integer, explode

Say I have a string like so `$thestring = "1,2,3,8,2"`.

If I `explode(',', $thestring)` it, I get an array of strings.  How do I explode it to an array of integers instead?

Comment: will your string contain integers and only comma??

Comment: @User, only integers and commas, nothing else

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int

Comment: @AndrasToth, right that is it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) also could be used:

```
$s = "1,2,3,8,2";
$ints = array_map('intval', explode(',', $s ));
var_dump( $ints );
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>      int(1)
  [1]=>      int(2)
  [2]=>      int(3)
  [3]=>      int(8)
  [4]=>      int(2)
}
```

Example [codepad](http://codepad.org/b4uEhB5r).

Answer (score 12):

Use something like this:

```
$data = explode( ',', $thestring );
array_walk( $data, 'intval' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Yes, I noticed I was wrong and was going to edit it back. But I find the PHP docs confusing, it says callable for first arg.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, see the link, callable is second, first is array. But anyway, yes, this is one of the biggest PHP problems. Some functions are with underscore, some are without. Some have one order, others have reverse. Strange.

Comment: @Prof.Falken well, i think your thinking of array_map?

Comment: This is no longer working in php 5.3 (see comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) . Instead use `$data = array_map('intval',$data);`

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you shouldn't really need to (PHP is generally good with handling casting strings and floats/ints), but if it is absolutely necessary, you can [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floatval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$arr = explode(',','1,2,3'); 
// use floatval if you think you are going to have decimals
array_walk($arr,'intval'); 
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

If you need something a bit more verbose, you can also look into [`settype`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php):

```
$arr = explode(",","1,2,3");
function fn(&$a){settype($a,"int");}
array_walk($f,"fn");
print_r($f);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

That could be particularly useful if you're trying to cast dynamically:

```
class Converter {
    public $type = 'int';
    public function cast(&$val){ settype($val, $this->type); }
}
$c = new Converter();

$arr = explode(",","1,2,3,0");
array_walk($arr,array($c, 'cast'));
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 0
)

// now using a bool
$c->type = 'bool';
$arr = explode(",","1,2,3,0");
array_walk($arr,array($c, 'cast'));
var_dump($arr); // using var_dump because the output is clearer.

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(true)
  [2]=>
  bool(true)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $thestring is an string then you will get an array of strings.

Just add (int) in front of the exploded values.

Or use the array_walk function:

```
$arr = explode(',', $thestring);
array_walk($arr, 'intval');
```

Comment: doesn't work for me checkout this link http://codepad.org/WwpN4J2x

Answer (score 0):

```
$thestring = "1,2,3,8,a,b,2";

$newArray = array();
$theArray = explode(",", $thestring);

print_r($theArray);

foreach ($theArray as $theData) {
  if (is_numeric($theData)) {
    $newArray[] = $theData;
  }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

// Output

Original array

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 8 [4] => a [5] => b [6] => 2 )
```

Numeric only array

```
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 8 [4] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=explode(',', $thestring);
$newstr   = '';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  $newstr .= $val; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think it procudes the expected result, it will produce a string like `12382`.