# Max function in PHP fails on strings?

Tags: php

Given this list.txt file:

```
9
10
19
```

Guess what?

`max(split("\n",$file_handle)) gives me 9`

`max(explode(PHP_EOL,$file_handle)) gives me 9`

Now, on a string:

`$string = "9
10
19";
max(split("\n",$string)) gives me 19`

Updated: When reading from a file, I get strings and max() can't seems to find the correct max when comparing string values?! 9 is bigger than 10. The same file content on a string works fine. file_get_contents()/fread() same issue.

Comment: What you've mentioned above for 90 is what I'd expect for a string comparison because it starts at the first character and 9 is greater than the first 1 in 100. I'm not sure the best way to do it in PHP but you probably want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int

Comment: Works fine: http://3v4l.org/qgnnZ. Something wrong with reading from file.

Comment: Yes, sectus, that's the issue. When reading from the file it get's interpreted as "string" and thus 9 is bigger than 10. I wonder why?

Comment: No, max works fine with number strings. Show how are you reading.

Comment: Seems it does not... when I convert to numbers it can successfully finds the correct max.

Comment: @billynoah I have updated the question. I am sorry for the confusion. It was code mixed with talk. :(

Comment: ok thanks.. have you tried `explode()` instead of `split()`?  I've never used `split` and it's deprecated.. not sure if that would have any bearing.

Comment: try `max(explode(PHP_EOL,$file_handle))` and let me know if that helps

Comment: @billynoah  explode() fails also. when seems to work when converting to numbers. The weird thing is from a string works fine. Go guess.

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump($file_handle);`?  Something tells me it doesn't contain what you think it does.  perhaps `max(explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('list.txt')))`;

Comment: @billynoah file_get_contents fails also

Comment: please, add var_dump of $file_handle.

Comment: http://zuma-design.com/shared/list.png

Comment: @billynoah With the exact same code, I get 9. Maybe php version?

Comment: Mystery finally solved: list.txt was in a DOS format! The dos end line character in use on the file was somehow causing PHP to interpret it as a string instead of an integer by default. In short, the difference is that the UNIX end-of-line character is a line feed/newline character (\n). The DOS/Windows end-of-line character is a carriage return, followed by a line feed/newline (\r\n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that EOL (end-of line) is "\n"?

Look at this answer:

[Explode PHP string by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)

And check this for EOL explanation:

[Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Comment: That was indeed the issue! The dos end line character in use on the file was somehow causing PHP to interpret it as a string instead of an integer by default. I converted list.txt file to use the unix line breaks instead of the dos breaks, and now script is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This solves it. Still a mystery to me why values come as string from file and as numbers from a string with the same content. Anyway, here's the fix:

```
max(array_map('intval', split("\n",$file_handle)));
```