# How to split the values of a php script and possibly do an average?

Tags: php

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>xxxxxx!</h2>
<?php
    $score = array();
    exec("D:\Users\Owner\Documents\a2 2>&1 D:\Users\Owner\Documents\212.wav D:\Users\Owner\Documents\StartUp\23sw1.wav", $score);
    echo '<h3>Score </h3>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'xxxxxxx: ' . $score[0];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of $score[0] is like  21 20 11 8 79 100 89. How can I split them? I am also interested in doing an average of it = ( 21 + 20+ 11+ 8 +79 +100+ 89)/7

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert array values from string to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like

```
$arr = explode(' ',$score[0]);
$average = array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
echo $average;
```

Comment: Actually, this did the trick: $average = array_sum($arr)/( count($arr) - 1); Yours counting up by 1.  Do u need to set $average = 0 ?

Comment: Is this method reliable - explode(' ',$score[0]) - if there are white spaces here are there then will it be off?

Answer (score 0):

//Create an array where have space, like this.

```
$scoreExp = explode(' ', $score[0]);
// start with 0 
$scorePlus = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($scoreExp);$i++){
    $scored = $scoreExp[$i];    
    $scorePlus = $scorePlus + $scored;
}
echo $scorePlus/count($scoreExp);
```

Comment: Even if your answer may solve the initial question, you should also leave a short description and explain why and how your code fixes the initial problem.

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [answer]