# how to make $_POST['value'] as numeric array to do foreach

Tags: php

I have a question here on how to parse a `$POST_['value'] (e.g 3785,3789,3790,3787 )` from a form to an `array($POST_['value'])` and do foreach. Please see the sample code below:

```
function someFunction(){
    $html = '';
    $int = $_POST['Ids']; //POST the value as 3785,3789,3790,3787
    $IDs = array($int);

    foreach ($IDs as $ID) {
        $intVal = '<int>' . $ID .'</int>';
        $html .= $intVal;
    }

    return $html;
}
```

however the result displays it as the ****whole string** rather than array**.
And if I put the `array(3785,3789,3790,3787)` like this, it will parse as array in foreach. How to convert the `$POST_['IDs']` to number or some sort in order to be recognised as array?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert array values from string to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
function someFunction(){
    $html = '';
    $int = $_POST['Ids']; //POST the value as 3785,3789,3790,3787
    $IDs = explode(',', $_POST['Ids']);

    foreach ($IDs as $ID) {
        $intVal = '<int>' . $ID .'</int>';
        $html .= $intVal;
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: That works well, thanks, maybe I don't understand about explode enough, I know its basic.

Comment: No Problem @MikeeTsai

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a quick fix to the following line:

```
<?php

$IDs = explode(",", $int);
```