# Convert all the elements of an array to individual strings

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert all elements of $values_x to individual strings. For eg:If it has (2010,2011,2012), i need it to be ('2010',2011','2012')

```
$values_x = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $series[0]['data'] ); $i++ ) {
    $values_x[] = $series[0]['data'][$i][0];
}

$values_y = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $series[0]['data'] ); $i++ ) {
    $values_y[] = $series[0]['data'][$i][1];
}

$categories = array(
    "label"  => $label_x,
    "values" => $values_x,
    "colors" => $eco_chart_colors,
);

$series = array("label" => null, "values" => array( array("data" => $values_y)));
```

Comment: What do you want `var_dump($values_x);` to return? What does it currently return?

Comment: it will return numbers. for eg: 2010, 2011, etc i want it to output '2010', '2011'

Comment: I think you need this but with strval http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int

Comment: strval didnt work either

Comment: You only need one loop to iterate both array synchronously.  Cast the ints to strings within that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply do following, You can see your output using following two lines of code.

```
$string_vals = array();
$string_vals[] = "'".$categories['values']."'";
```

Simply Concatenate Single Quotation marks.
So, Something like this

```
$string_vals = array();
foreach($categories as $cat){
    $string_vals[] = "'".$cat['values']."'";
}                    
print_r($string_vals);
```