# String to array conversion in php

Tags: php, laravel

I got the string from the ajax and passed the string in url as 
1,2,3,4,5,6

After using explode function,
i.e. `$explode_id = explode(',', $request->data);`
I got the output as
["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

But I want the data as:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

How do I get it?
And it should not be like ["1,2,3,4,5,6"]
Because I want to compare the data in:

```
  $product_id = Product::where('name', 'like','%'.$main.'%')->where('id', $explode_id)->pluck('id');
```

I got the answer here.
Am passing the id that i want to match in URL like

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   var days = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: '/getcreatedat',
        data: { 'days': days },
        success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
        function successFunc(data, status) {
          var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
          window.location.href = pageURL+ '/' +data;
        }   
        function errorFunc(xhr, error) {
             console.log(error);
        }
    }
});
```

The next time I click the function:
url passing the id's double the time

Comment: Are you trying to do a `IN (1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: Am using laravel. It won't work

Comment: no. This is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert array values from string to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int)

Comment: ya.. this answer ids given already. Thank You so much

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Kayal try it with array_map() with inval like below:

```
<?php
    $explode_id = array_map('intval', explode(',', $request->data));
```

Comment: Thank you so much . You made my day special

Comment: I have one more problem too

Comment: @Kayal you are turning question to wrong way, previous and current cases are different, i really suggest you to ask a new question for that with your full ajax code with more explanation because your question stuff is not sufficient to answer your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974228/ajax-data-update-for-each-ajax-function

Answer (score 19):

You can just `json_decode` it.

```
$explode_id = json_decode($request->data, true);
```

Also, if you're trying to do a `IN()` condition, you can use:

```
->whereIn('id', $explode_id);
```

Comment: I think this solution better than the `explode`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace('"','',$string[$i]);`
inside a for loop for each array element or else you can do it as

```
$intVal = (int)$string[$i];
```

in side a for loop

Comment: I used it. But there is no change in the output

Comment: `"` is not a string part of output `["1","2","3","4","5","6"]`

Comment: I have edited the answer. Did you try the second method?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way, try this...

```
 $a = "1,2,3,4,5";
 $b= preg_split("/[,]/",$a);
 print_r($b);
```