# Convert string arra into array of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving params like this `"[[201], [511], [3451]]"`, I want to convert it into `[201, 511, 3451]`

Comment: I think the link below will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/convert-array-values-from-string-to-int

Comment: [I think the link below will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/convert-array-values-from-string-to-int)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say *params* is what you're receiving, you can use scan and map to use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), look for the digits in the response and then map each item in the array to an integer:

```
params = "[[201], [511], [3451]]"
params_array = params.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

What we are doing here is we are looking through the string and selecting only the digits with the [Scan](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan) method, afterwards we get a string array so to convert it into integers we use the [Map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) method. As per the map method, thanks to [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) for the update on it.

Comment: Great observation @CarySwoveland, editing

Comment: No attribution is needed. Incidentally, to keep your answers "clean", if you want to make an attribution I suggest you do it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It will help you!

```
str_arr = "[[201], [511], [3451]]"

JSON.parse(str_arr).flatten

or

eval(str_arr).flatten
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here is an interesting way (note that it only works in case your params is an array string)

```rb
arr1 = instance_eval("[1,2,3]")
puts arr1.inspect # [1,2,3]

arr2 = instance_eval("[[201], [511], [3451]]")
puts arr2.inspect # [[201], [511], [3451]]
```

Comment: You could use `p` instead of writing `puts` with `inspect`

Comment: Note the Rails tag and the use of the word _params_ which implies form data sent by the user agent. Doing this will allow the HTTP client to evaluate arbitrary Ruby code on the server.

Comment: @LamPhan : Why `instance_eval` and not `eval`?

Comment: @user1934428 when i answered this question i even haven't thought about security, so `instance_eval` here is used for some cases the input array string maybe contains some specific values of the instance of the invoke class such as "[X, Y, Z]".

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make a sanity check that you don't get malevolent code injected:

```
raise "Can not convert #{params}" if /[^\[\]\d]/ =~ params
```

Now you can assert that your string is safe:

```
params.untaint
```

and then convert

```
arr = eval(params).flatten
```

or

```
arr = eval(params).flatten(1)
```

depending on what exactly you want to receive if you have deeply-nested "arrays" in your string.